# PowerShell Receive-Job does not work in script

Tags: powershell

When I execute `$job = Start-Job { dir }` an then `Receive-Job $job` in PowerShell console I get normal output. But when I make similar .ps1 script and run it there is no output. Other commands work correctly. How do I receive job result in scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the job to finish:

```
Start-Job { dir } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Thanks for pipelining sample.

Answer (score 4):

Just try wait job is completed before receive.

```
$job = Start-Job { dir }
Wait-Job $job | out-null
receive-job $job
```

other way

```
$job = Start-Job { dir }
while ($job.state -ne "Completed") {}
receive-job $job
```